# putting a hyperlink inside of a label in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, redirect, label, hyperlink

i have this in my vb.net code.
label1.text = "Click on THIS ONE to proceed"

Now for the THIS ONE in the label text i want to give it a hyperlink or response.redirect. Any ideas how i can do this?

Comment: Did you try label1.text = "<a href=''>Click on THIS ONE to proceed</a>"?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation here would be to do it the following way.

Replace the Label control with a Literal then do it this way

```
literal1.Text = "Click on <a href='yoururl'>THIS ONE</a> to proceed"
```

Comment: What should be imported? e.g System.Web.UI

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this inside a single label.

Instead, you can use a [`Literal` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx) and set the `Text` to include an `<a>` tag.

Alternatively, you can use a server-side hyperlink control.